# Help with hotel queries

Tags: sql-server

Hello I have a database in Microsoft SQL Server with tables relevant to a reservation system for a hotel/villa and need help creating a few queries to obtain relevant data:

To be able to find out a list of guests checking out on a specific date, grouped by villa type and providing a total number for that day (i.e. a count).

For that query I think I'd have to use 2 relevant tables a guest reservation and reservation table:

```
create table guest_reservation(confirm_no int,
agent_id int,
g_name varchar (30),
g_phone varchar (10));

create table reservation(
confirm_no int,
credit_card_no char (16),
res_checkin_date datetime,
res_checkout_date datetime,
default_villa_type char (1),
price_plan char (1));



I thought using a query like this would help, but it didn't seem to: 

SELECT g_name, villa_type, COUNT(*) 
FROM guest_reservation, reservation 
WHERE guest_reservation.confirm_no = reservation.confirm_no 
  AND res_checkout_date = ‘insert date for when you would want to check out here’ 
GROUP BY villa_type;
```

Ideas/help?

EDIT: I think I figured out the 1st question...

Another query I wanted help on was that if a guest wanted a certain type of room then if that type of room would be available on the dates they wanted to stay on.

I used JUST the Reservation table but I'm not sure if that quite would do what I want, here's what I currently had:

```
Select villa_type from reservation
where res_check_in_date not between '2011-10-08' and '2011-10-09'
and res_check_out_date not between '2011-10-08' and '2011-10-09'
```

Comment: Why all the `alter` statements, just put it into the table declaration at the beginning to make it easier to read.

Comment: Sorry was just trying to show how I created the tables, keys involved and then what I was trying to do afterwards with that last query...it's mostly the last query I'm asking about as in how to use it appropriately to get the output I need?

Comment: please consolidate it into one `CREATE TABLE` statement, it will be much easier to help  you.  We do need to see the table structure to evaluate the query.

Comment: There JNK, should be good now :)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of time spans, you may find it helpful, nay, necessary, to create a Calendar table which is simply a static list of days in the calendar. These are almost always created in BI projects for data analysis.

What this object allows you to do is join from you Reservation table to the Calendar table, giving you a list of distinctive dates which encompass the time span. Here's a code sample:

```
inner join calendar
on calendar.date between reservation.res_checkin_date and reservation.res_checkout_date
```

For example, If I'm checking in today (4/12) and checking out on Thursday (4/14), joining to the calendar table will product 3 distinct rows, one each for 4/12, 4/13, 4/14. In terms of checking availability, this is a much clearer picture of who occupies what, when.

Additionally, there are some code nuances you may want to be aware of, such as using a DATE instead of DATETIME, to eliminate the possibility of times producing unexpected results. If you need a full DATETIME type, there are ways to [efficiently query the DATE in a DATETIME](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/17/efficiently-query-the-date-in-datetime/).